# Unable to print right floating point value

Tags: c, floating-point, arm

I have my ZC706 board with dual arm cortex 32bit one. I am trying to run an algorithm over it, as a part of the code it has floating point values.

```
uint32_t int Ts = 69912;
float Ts_pico;
Ts_pico = 20*(10^-12)*Ts;
printf("Time stamp in picoseconds is %f", Ts_pico);
```

And it prints a value 4272595456.000000 instead of 1.39824*(10^-6)

So I tested by printing

```
printf("The float point value is %f", 1.39824);
```

It was fine printing out the following value.

Next, when i tested by printing

```
double f = 10^-6;
printf("The flloat point value is %f", f);
```

The value it has printed is -14401872.000000

How can I solve the issue with floating point values?

Comment: ^ is a bitwise XOR operator, you should replace anything in the form of a * 10^power to aEpower. 20 * 10^-12 become 20E-12 and 10^-6 become 1E-6

Comment: Please a) turn on all compiler warnings, and read them; b) get a book on C, there might be more gaps in what you know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Didn't you want `10e-12` rather `10^-12`?

`10e-12` is a *floating point* `double` *constant*, although do note that `1e-12` is `10` raised to the `-12`<sup>th</sup> power. Your `^` is an abuse of the XOR operator.

Comment: 10 to the power of -12 is `1e-12`, not `10e-12`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Indeed. It's not the first time I've been an order of magnitude out in a calculation. Thank you.

Comment: Minor: In C, it is a floating point double _constant_.  _Literals_ in C and `double` literals in C++ can have their address taken.

Comment: @chux: Thank you, precision is important, and I've made the change.